# Exporting an excel range to an EMF file in specified location

Tags: c#, excel, range, vsto

I'm having trouble getting my range exported to an emf file. It does get copied to the clipboard because I can paste it after the exception is thrown:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   N1Narrator.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   <--referencing 'img'

Here's my code:

```
if (intersectRange != null && name.RefersToRange.Cells.Count > 1)
{                            
       name.RefersToRange.CopyPicture(Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, Excel.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlPicture);

      const int CF_ETAFILE = 14;
                                IntPtr intptr;

                                System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile myMetaFile = null;
                                if (ClipboardFunctions.OpenClipboard(IntPtr.Zero))
                                {
                                    if (ClipboardFunctions.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_ETAFILE) != 0)
                                    {
                                        intptr = ClipboardFunctions.GetClipboardData(CF_ETAFILE);
                                        myMetaFile = new Metafile(intptr, true);
                                        ClipboardFunctions.CloseClipboard();
                                        myMetaFile.Save(@"C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Temp\Narrative1\N1Appraisal\ExcelTables\testtable.emf", ImageFormat.Emf);
                                    }
                                }  

}
```

I've looked into DataObject() as well for the Clipboard but to no avail.  I don't want to use the Chart method, it'll be too slow.

Comment: Which clipboard are you using? System.Windows or System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Oh my god it worked never mind, I was an idiot and forgot to change XLBitmap back to XLPicture.  Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the problem is using an `Image` datatype to save an EMF vector image **not** a bitmap from the Clipboard, you can [use this code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/837756df-afc9-47d6-be91-ca0a711ea8fe/retrieving-a-metafile-from-the-clipboard?forum=csharpgeneral) :

```
//using System.Runtime.InteropServices;  
public class ClipboardFunctions  
{  
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenClipboard", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]  
    public static extern bool OpenClipboard(IntPtr hWnd);  

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "EmptyClipboard", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]  
    public static extern bool EmptyClipboard();  

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetClipboardData", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]  
    public static extern IntPtr SetClipboardData(int uFormat, IntPtr hWnd);  

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "CloseClipboard", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]  
    public static extern bool CloseClipboard();  

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetClipboardData", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]  
    public static extern IntPtr GetClipboardData(int uFormat);  

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "IsClipboardFormatAvailable", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]  
    public static extern short IsClipboardFormatAvailable(int uFormat);  
}  

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    const int CF_ETAFILE = 14;  
    IntPtr intptr;  

    System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile myMetaFile = null;  
    if (ClipboardFunctions.OpenClipboard(this.Handle))  
    {  
        if (ClipboardFunctions.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_ETAFILE) != 0)  
        {  
            intptr = ClipboardFunctions.GetClipboardData(CF_ETAFILE);  
            myMetaFile = new System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile(intptr, true);  
            ClipboardFunctions.CloseClipboard();  
            myMetaFile.Save(@"c:\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Here is a similar [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868816/clipboard-getdata-returns-null-when-it-should-not).

If you're not sure what format the image inside Excel is, then instead of calling `Clipboard.GetImage()`, try calling `Clipboard.GetDataObject()`

This returns an IDataObject, which you can in turn query by calling dataObject.GetFormats(). GetFormats() returns the type formats supported by the Clipboard object - there may be a more precise format supported that you can use to extract the data (but I am pretty sure Excel does use EMF for graphs).

Comment: I edited your question accordingly. Is `Image` from the [System.Drawing namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or some type you created in a project named N1Narrator? Did you try my method?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy I apologize I'm new to this.  I tried your method, but I'm not using a button, so what do i place as an argument in the .opensclipboard if condition?  Also I tried the IDataObject, I'm editing my post to show both IDataObject and your method.  I commented out the IDataObject code.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for my lack of skills in Stackoverflow comments.

```
sel.CopyPicture(Appearance: Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, Format: Excel.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);
var image = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetImage();
```

This code works fine for me for Excel 2013 addin. Notice I am using xlBitmap instead of xlPicture. Does this meet your requirements? Or I will give a try with xlPicture as well.

Comment: Your code is executing, and then I save the image var to a directory.  Open the image in paint and they're blank, with the same dimensions of the range, it appears.  I've tried 'bmp' and 'emf'

Comment: 1) Please note that Jeremy's answer is the right answer for xlPicture. My code only seems to work for xlBitmap. 2) image.Save(@"C:\temp\test.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);    ---- This works fine for me to save image as bmp.

Comment: Please note that image variable I use is of System.Drawing.Image type.

Comment: Okay, I just edited my post with the code but now it's not saving it at all.  I'm not getting any error/exceptions either.  And i do have the clipboard functions at the top of my file

Comment: If you are using XlBitmap, my code will work fine. Again, will it suffice your needs? If you need to use xlPicture, I will have to look more into Jeremy's code - I haven't played with it.

Comment: Yea I need to use xlPicture, I tried your code, but when it saves and I open the file, it's blank;  it only has the range dimensions. When I use xlpicture, on the the other hand, it captures the whole thing. just can't get it save as an emf.